# if session redirect to homepage

Tags: php

```
if(!$_SESSION['username']) {


     $ip = $db->real_escape_string(VisitorIP());
         $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
         $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $salt = "****";
     $password = md5($password . $salt);
         $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
         $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1){
            $bannedq = $db->query("SELECT banned FROM TABLE WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
            $banned = $bannedq->fetch_row();
            if($banned[0] == "1") {
            $failedLogin="1";
            $message = 'You are banned and you cannot login';
            } else {
                                $ip = $db->real_escape_string(VisitorIP());
                $db->query("UPDATE h_users SET lastlogin=now(), lastip = '$ip' WHERE username='$username'");
                                header("Location: home");
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                $failedLogin = "1";
                $message   = 'Username or Password WRONG!';
                }
            }
} else {
header("location: home");
}
```

Hello programmers,
I am trying to setup a login system in my website. Until now it was working fine but when the session is set and the user gets redirected to the homepage now if he goes to the login screen and the session is set i want him to redirect to the homepage and not see the login screen again.
But my after i added this part :

```
if(!$_SESSION['username']) {
```

it does not work

Comment: You should add `exit;` after each header. Many a times, that fixes quite a few things. By not doing so, your code wants to continue to execute, regardless. Using error reporting would help in this instance.

Comment: Are you starting the session correctly?

Comment: do you have session_start(); on that page

Comment: @chikurubhi OP does have it just below `header("Location: home");` it's just in the wrong place.

Comment: @Fred-ii-yes i didn't see it at the top that's why i was asking :)

Comment: Btw, even though you're adding salt to MD5, it's still old and considered broken. Look into using `password_hash()`. Your users will thank you for it. ;-) Plus, look into using prepared statements too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take your session start and put it there before you use it, so write this before your if statement:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username']) {
//...
```

And delete this one here:

```
/...
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
/...
```

(Also i would add a `die();` or `exit();` after each header, it makes sure nothing gets executed after the header)

Comment: deleting the $_SESSION['username'] wouldn't help me, 
I would have to reconstruct the entire script if i do that :/

Comment: @ErgjanJaha I never wrote that you have to remove this! Just put the session start before you use the array! Also then remove the old session start!

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys thanks for your help <3 <3
I changed my code to this and everything went fine

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
     $ip = $db->real_escape_string(VisitorIP());
         $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
         $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $salt = "ho073";
     $password = md5($password . $salt);
         $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
         $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1){
            $bannedq = $db->query("SELECT banned FROM TABLE WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
            $banned = $bannedq->fetch_row();
            if($banned[0] == "1") {
            $failedLogin="1";
            $message = 'You are banned and you cannot login';
            } else {
                                $ip = $db->real_escape_string(VisitorIP());
                $db->query("UPDATE TABLE SET lastlogin=now(), lastip = '$ip' WHERE username='$username'");
                                header("Location: home");
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $failedLogin = "1";
                $message   = 'Username or Password WRONG!';
                }
            }
    }
        include'templates/login.html';
} else {
header("location: home");
die();
}
```

Much love for you <3